# View pager and ImageView not showing android

Tags: android

I got a problem. When im using a pagerView everything inside is showing up beside ImageView.

I'm using this :

```
<!-- activity_screen_slide.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

And i use this for fragment

```
package com.example.gebruiker.drumio.SlideScreenTrackPreview;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.gebruiker.drumio.R;


public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView hihat;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
        container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) 
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.track_preview_test,container,false);
        hihat =(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        hihat.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        hihat.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Except the button, nothing is showing up.

Here is the code for the activity that i use :

```
package com.example.gebruiker.drumio.SlideScreenTrackPreview;


public class ScreenSliderActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPagerAdapter = new 
  ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}


private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       return new TestFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but I had to make some assumptions about how your project is set up; that suggests that the problem may be in your Activity code.  Could you post that code here where I can take a look at it please?  Also, you might consider posting or inlining your margin dimensions and temporarily using a drawable built into Android, to make it easier for others to set up a compilable project.

Comment: @AaronHarris i edit the post with the code for the activity. I also dont understand what you mean saying temporaily using a drawable ?

Comment: The comment about the drawable was just pointing out that the drawable is local to your project, so anyone trying to figure out what the problem is will have to substitute some other drawable when they set up their own copy of your project.  Not a big deal, since it's not the problem at hand, but it would make it easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity works for me if you inherit from [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead of from [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html).  I don't know why; maybe somebody with more experience can elucidate.